# Why haven't the leagues moved on to 2015?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I've went and checked the leagues and it's still shows the last week of 2014:

[image: December]

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow

[image: 2014]

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow

The leagues are usually recalculated at midnight (utc). Is there a reason for that?

Comment: What would you expect to see if the leagues on the year 2015 would have started counted *that* midnight? Nothing... At this point of time (midnight from 2014 to 2015) nobody has earned any rep in 2015...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The leagues are generated *once per day*.

The last time they were generated was at midnight and no data for 2015 could have been collected at that point, the league data can only take activity *up to that point* into account. If only data up to 2014-12-31 23:59:59 can be used, there is nothing to calculate for 2015.

Comment: As always.. an off-by-one error. That makes sense, thank you.